# How to deserialize a HttpEntity containing Array Lists from Rest API call to a Java Object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, arraylist, jackson

I am trying to deserialize ResponseEntity<> returned by a Rest API call to Java Objects and had been unsuccessful. Following is the POJO

```
    public class Application {
           private String name;
           private List<String> location;
    }
```

Here is the Rest API call and deserializing

```
public List<Application> getApps(){
       List<Application> = new ArrayList<>();
       ResponseEntity<String> returnObject = oauthRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, 
           String.class);
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       Response response = objectMapper.readValue(returnObject.getBody(),
           Response.class);
       apps = objectMapper.convertValue(
                    response.getItems(),
                    new TypeReference<List<Application>>() {
                    }
            );
       return apps;
}
```

Response Java Object is

```
    public class Response {
           private String code;
           private String message;
           private String Status;
           private List<T> items;
    }
```

Contents of return response (returnObject.getBody()) is

```
    <Response>
        <code>200</code>
        <message></message>
        <status>SUCCESSFUL</status>
        <items>
            <items>
                <name>App1</name>
                <location>
                    <location>location1</location>
                </location>
            </items>
            <items>
                <name>App2</name>
                <location>
                    <location>location1</location>
                </location>
            </items>
        </items>
    </Response>
```

It is difficult to understand why additional tags for List is being added to the JSON string. The deserializing is failing when it encounters location tag within location. Following are the error logs

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: (String)"<PagedResponse><code>200</code><message/><status>SUCCESSFUL</status><items><items><name>App1</name><location>" line: 1, column: 2]
```

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
Modified the "ObjectMapper" to "XmlMapper" and received the below error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
     at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.dto.Application["location"])
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3750)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3678)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a JSON parser to parse XML.
It fails at the beginning: `line: 1, column: 2`

Comment: modified ObjectMapper to XmlMapper to receive the above-updated error. Thank you for your help

Comment: The locations are not simple strings, but rather objects that contain a location string. So you could try to make a new class `Location` with a field `String location` and change your `Application` to have `List<Location> locations`

Comment: @user15148356, agree. Define your response class structure the same as XML.

Answer (score 2):

If your response is in XML format user XMLMapper. Here is the reference
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: modified ObjectMapper to XmlMapper to receive the above updated error. Thank you for you help